# What does the Gedit plugin called "Dashboard" do and/or provide?

Tags: gedit, plugins

What does the **"Dashboard"** plugin do? It's description says "A Dashboard for new tabs.", but I can't see what's changed after I enable it or what it lets me do differently. I  don't see anything like a "dashboard" anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gedit Dashboard plugin uses Zeitgeist to display recently or most used items in new Gedit tabs. You can search both recently and most used items and also, the plugin generates previews which "try to jump directly to some code or text from your work".

Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/gedit-dash-new-tab-gedit-plugin-powered.html

Here are a few screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

That's what it's supposed to do, BUT it doesn't (tested in Ubuntu 14.04).
As a result, [a bug has been reported on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit-plugins/+bug/1281169).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if this "Getting Started" tab would always display when the plugin is enabled?

Comment: This plugin is still in the ubuntu repo but it doesn't seem to work anymore. Ah well.